# Building a web service: what options do I have?

Tags: web-services, rest, httpwebrequest, lamp, push-notification

I'm looking to build my first web service and I would like to be pointed in the right direction right from the start.

Here are the interactions that must take place:

- First, a smartphone or computer will send a chunk of data to my web service.
- The web service will persist the information to the database.
- Periodically, an algorithm will access and modify the database.
- The algorithm will periodically bundle data and send it out to smartphones or computer (how?)

The big question is: **What basic things do I need to learn to in order to implement something like this?**

---

Now here are the little rambling questions that I've also got rolling around in my head.  Feel free to answer these if you wish.  (...maybe consider them extra credit?)

- I've heard a lot of good things about RESTful services, I've read the wiki article, and I've even played around with the Twitter's webservice which is RESTful.  Is this the obvious way to go?  Or should I still consider something else?
- What programming language do I use to persist things to the database?  I'm thinking php will be the first choice for this.
- What programming language do I use to interact with the database?  I'm thinking anything is probably acceptable, right?
- Do I have to worry about concurrent access to the database, or does MySQL handle that for me?  (I'm fairly new to databases too.)
- How on earth do I send information back? Obviously, if it's a reply to an HTTP request that's no problem, but there will be times when the reply may take quite a long time to compute.  Should I just let the HTTP request remain outstanding until I have the answer?
- There will be times when I need to send information to a smartphone regardless of whether or not information has been sent to me. How can I *push* information to my users?

Other information that may help you know where I'm coming from:

- I am pretty familiar with Java, C#, C++, and Python.  I have played around with PHP, Javascript, and Ruby.
- I am relatively new to databasing, but I get the basic idea.
- I've already set up my server and I'm using a basic LAMP stack.  My understanding of *L*, *A*, *M* and *P* is fairly rudimentary.

Comment: consider  breaking your massive question into several smaller ones

Comment: You're biting off an awful lot at once, here -- maybe start smaller, with smaller questions.

Comment: I think the main question is the one in bold text. For instance... what *general* things must I learn?  Are there frameworks that are typically used for this?  Is there a series of wikipedia entries that I should read?  Don't feel compelled to give specific answers to the rambling questions. (Although any answers here would be greatly appreciated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Language**: Python for it's ease of use assuming the [GIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) is not a particular concern for your requirements (e.g. multi-threading). It has drivers for most databases and  supports numerous protocols. There are several web frameworks for it - the most popular probably being [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com).

**Protocols**: if you are HTTP focused study [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) and [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer). Note, SOAP tends to be verbose, which causes problems moving volumes of data. On the other hand, if you are looking at other options study [socket programming](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/sockets/) and perhaps some sort of binary format such as Google's [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/). Flash is also a possibility (see: [Flash Remoting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format)). Note, binary options require users install something onto their machine (e.g. applet or standalone app).

**Replies**: if the process is long running, and the client should be notified when it's done, I would recommend developing an app for the client. Browser's can be programmed with JavaScript to periodically poll, or a Flash movie can be embedded to real time updates, but these are somewhat tricky bits of browser programming. If you're dealing with wireless phones, look at SMS. Otherwise I would just provide a way for clients to get status, but not send out notification (e.g. push vs. pull). As @jcomea_ictx wrote, AJAX is an option if it's a browser based solution - study [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

**Concurrency**: understand what [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) means with regards to databases. Think about what should happen if you receive multiple writes to the same data - database may not necessarily solve this problem the way you'd want.

Comment: This is a very good answer.  Thank you for the myriad of links to reading material. However please clarify two points: 1) *Would* GIL be a concern for me?  I intend to have one thread/process (I don't know which yet) handling requests and another thread/process continuously processing and modifying the database. 2) You seem to be advocating poll then pull rather than push, right?

Comment: IF you're unsure if the GIL is an issue it's probably not. You'd need to be doing numerous CPU bound activities before it becomes an issue. As push/poll - push if you've built a client independent of the browser that can receive the message - poll if with a browser over AJAX investigate the JavaScript function setInterval().

Answer (score 1):

Please, for the love of programming, don't use PHP if you're already comfortable with Python. The latter makes for far cleaner, more maintainable code. Not that it's impossible to *write* good code in PHP, but it's a relative rarity. You can use Python for all the server-end stuff including MySQL interaction, with the MySQLdb module. Either with standard CGI, or FCGI, or mod_python.

As for the database, use of transactions will eliminate conflicts. But you can usually design a system in such a way that conflicts will not happen. For example, use of auto-incrementing primary-key IDs on each insert will make sure that every entry is unique.

You can "pull" data with Javascript, perhaps using AJAX methodology, or "push" using SMS or other technologies.

When replies take a while to compute, you can "poll" using AJAX. This is a very common technique. The server just returns "we are working on this" (or equivalent) with a built-in refresh until the results are ready.

I'm no expert on REST, but AJAX, especially when using polling rather than simply responding to user input, can be said to violate RESTful principles. But you can be a purist, or you can do whatever works. It's up to you.

I don't believe I've ever used any "push" technologies other than SMS, and that was years ago when many companies had free SMS gateways. So if you want to "push" data, better hope someone else joins in the conversation!

Comment: SMS probably won't work in my case b/c it tends to cost to much considering how often I will be sending information.  Keep talking though because I'm definitely listening!

Answer (score 0):

Use Java. The latest version of [Java EE 6](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayk.html) makes coding RESTful and SOAP services a breeze, and it interoperates with databases very easily as well.

The benefits of using a true language instead of a script are: full server-side state, strong typing, multithreading, and countless other things that may or may not come in handy, but knowing they are available makes your project future proof.

Comment: hmm, what's "full server-side state"? Python has strong typing and multithreading. Java is a great language but let's avoid the hyperbole.